# Segmentation Fault - Invalid read of size 8

Tags: c++, string, vector, segmentation-fault

For some reason the following C++ code results in a segmentation fault:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string charToString(char c)
{
    stringstream ss;
    string s;
    ss << c;
    ss >> s;

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> stringTable;

    for(int c = 0; c < 256; ++c){
        string s = charToString(c);
        stringTable[c] = s;
    }
}
```

Valgrind reports the error `Invalid read of size 8` on the line

```
stringTable[c] = s;
```

But I can't see what's wrong with this line. So what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Your vector is empty. You could use push_back() to populate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing off the end of the `vector`.  Give the `vector` an initial size with

```
vector<string> stringTable(256);
```